# Android to Webservice. Values not being passed

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, web-services

So hi. I currently have web service that looks like this

```
    [WebMethod]
    public bool SyncGeneralDataToServer(string macaddress, string userid,
                                string password, string computername,
                                string dateupdated, string q1, string a1
                                , string q2, string a2, string q3, string a3
                                , string q4, string a4, string q5, string a5
                                , string location, bool onsite)
    {
        MTKBL = new MobileTKBL();
        bool result;
        try
        {
            result = MTKBL.SyncToServer(macaddress, userid,
                                     password, computername,
                                     dateupdated, q1, a1
                                    , q2, a2, q3, a3
                                    , q4, a4, q5, a5
                                    , location, onsite);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            result = false;
        }


        return result;
    }
```

And i have a android method that looks like this

```
        public boolean SyncLocalGeneralDataToServer(String macaddress, String userid,
        String password, String computername,
        String dateupdated, String q1, String a1
        , String q2, String a2, String q3, String a3
        , String q4, String a4, String q5, String a5
        , String location, boolean onsite)
{
    boolean result = false;

    String SOAP_ACTION = "http://MTKAndroidService.org/SyncGeneralDataToServer";
    String METHOD_NAME = "SyncGeneralDataToServer";

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);        

    PropertyInfo[] propInfos = new PropertyInfo[17];

    propInfos[0]= setPropertyInfo("macaddress",macaddress,String.class);
    propInfos[1]= setPropertyInfo("userid",userid,String.class);
    propInfos[2]= setPropertyInfo("macaddress",password,String.class);
    propInfos[3]= setPropertyInfo("computername",computername,String.class);
    propInfos[4]= setPropertyInfo("dateupdated",dateupdated,String.class);
    propInfos[5]= setPropertyInfo("q1",q1,String.class);
    propInfos[6]= setPropertyInfo("q2",q2,String.class);
    propInfos[7]= setPropertyInfo("q3",q3,String.class);
    propInfos[8]= setPropertyInfo("q4",q4,String.class);
    propInfos[9]= setPropertyInfo("q5",q5,String.class);
    propInfos[10]= setPropertyInfo("a1",a1,String.class);
    propInfos[11]= setPropertyInfo("a2",a2,String.class);
    propInfos[12]= setPropertyInfo("a3",a3,String.class);
    propInfos[13]= setPropertyInfo("a4",a4,String.class);
    propInfos[14]= setPropertyInfo("a5",a5,String.class);
    propInfos[15]= setPropertyInfo("location",location,String.class);
    propInfos[16]= setPropertyInfo("onsite",onsite,boolean.class);

    for(int i =0; i < propInfos.length; i++)
    {
         request.addProperty(propInfos[i]);
    }

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true; // put this only if the web service is .NET one
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {

        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        Log.i("myApp", response.toString());
        if(response.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
            result = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}

private PropertyInfo setPropertyInfo(String name,Object value,Object type)
{
    PropertyInfo propInfo =new PropertyInfo();
    propInfo.setName(name);
    propInfo.setValue(value);
    propInfo.setType(type);
    return propInfo;
}
```

And ive checked the property info values are correct and complete. The problem is the web service accepts the request but inserts null values in the database. What am i missing here?

Comment: When you debugged the service, did you see the correct values in the variables going to this method?  result = MTKBL.SyncToServer(macaddress, userid,
                                     password, computername,
                                     dateupdated, q1, a1
                                    , q2, a2, q3, a3
                                    , q4, a4, q5, a5
                                    , location, onsite);

Comment: You mean in the browser locally? Yes it succesfully saves it in the database meaning it passed the values in the server. But if its from android no. All the values are null. Thats why im asking this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your namespace URL (both .net and android sides) probably has a colon in it, eg http:// - remove the http:// part from the namespace and try again.

Comment: Well there was actually a wrong spelling in the url that caused the problem. Tnx for the heads up though. you directed me to check it.